# redireccionar desde mi metodo public void a un xhtml

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hice una validación en un método de tipo `boolean`. ¿Cómo se hace desde un `método`public void para redireccionar? Yo sé que un método string con `return` basta pero no sé en un metodo de firma `void`

Método:

```
public void login() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage message = null;
    boolean loggedIn = false;

    if(nombre != null && nombre.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
        loggedIn = true;            
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Bienvenido", nombre);
    } else {
        loggedIn = false;
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error de usuario", "Credenciales invalidas");
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
}
```

Comment: Imagino que estás llamando al método mediante ajax, ¿correcto? De ser así, lo mejor sería actualizar el modelo y un campo `h:hidden` de lado del cliente desde la info del servidor y crear una acción post ajax para leer el valor de dicho campo y evaluar si debes realizar el redirect o no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi opinión, la mejor solución en este caso es modificar la declaración de tu método de forma que devuelva un `String` con la ruta a la que redireccionar. En caso de fallar la validación un retorno de `null` sería suficiente para parar la navegación.
Así, tu código quedaría:

```
public String login() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage message = null;
    boolean loggedIn = false;

    if(nombre != null && nombre.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
        loggedIn = true;            
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Bienvenido", nombre);
    } else {
        loggedIn = false;
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error de usuario", "Credenciales invalidas");
        return null;
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    return "rutaAInicio";
}
```

Siendo "rutaAInicio" la ruta a tu xhtml.

Answer (score 1):

Para redireccionar utilizas necesitas algo como esto:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("ruta/de/archivo");`